# How would I set the width of a div but have it display inline?

Tags: html, css

I now I can't set the width of a div that's being displayed inline, but how would I do something similar?

I have a series of labels that I want to be all aligned to the right. Some of the labels have icons to their right, these all must be aligned as well. But the issue is that the labels that don't have icons to their right end up being un-aligned.

HTML:This is a label next to an icon

```
<div class="span2 pagination-right workspec-status-container">
  <span class="label wip">WIP</span>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-icon" data-html="true" data-
target="#workspec-popover-31" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="" title=""><i 
class="fam information"></i></a>
</div>
```

This is a label without an icon

```
<div class="span2 pagination-right workspec-status-container">
  <span class="label not-started">Not Started</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Change it to `inline-block`..?

Answer (score 0):

In some selector that will affect the desired div, add the following:

display: inline-block

Regards,

Guillermo